# Split based on a distance list and capacity

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble with splitting based on a known order with a secondary criterion in addition to distance. I have tried to manually loop through my list and cluster them based on a greedy method. But it seems inefficient, if there is a more efficient `scipy` package that can do the same thing and someone can point me towards it, that would be greatly appreciated.

So I have a list of nodes in a specified order.

```
list_of_nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I have a distance list which contains the distances between the nodes.

```
distanceList = [d_01, d_12, d_23, d_34, d_45, d_56, d_67, d_78, d_89]
```

Lastly, I have a demand list which contains the demand at each node.

```
demandList = [dm_0, dm_1, dm_2, dm_3, dm_4, dm_51, dm_6, dm_7, dm_8, dm_9]
```

I want to be able to split this list such that nodes of a certain max distance and max demand of each other are grouped together.

```
groups = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

The groups list indicates that nodes 7, 8, 9 belong together as their distance (e.g. d_78 + d_89 < max distance) and their demand (e.g. dm_7 + dm_8 + dm_9 < max demand) are less than the specified maximum. Since the order of the list is given, I am only splitting based on the distance between points and not the full matrix of distance.

Comment: You don't have a full distance matrix there anyway...

Comment: I see what you are saying, splitting is more appropriate here.

Comment: So why do you think this is inefficient? To me it seems there is an obvious O(n) strategy?

Comment: My current implementation is - start with the smallest distance (e.g. d_89). Look at the neighboring nodes and sequentially add the neighbor node with the shortest distance into the group while checking for the max distance and max demand constraint. Making sure to keep a reference of all the nodes added into the groups. Once it reaches the max distance or max demand constraint, I look for the next shortest pair not in an existing group and continue until all the nodes are considered.

Comment: Based on your description, I would have suggested to just start with the first, merge the next until the constraint is violated, repeat. Without a well-defined quality, it is as good a solution.